# QGIS map file to be viewed on both mac and pc platforms

Tags: qgis, convert

Im teaching a class where some students have QGIS installed on their macs and I'm using a pc.  Although the file structure is the same mac reference files differently than the pc and I get data link errors when I open a students map project.

Any quick conversion methods?  I can do it a link at a time but that seems a bit slow to me.

Comment: are you using relative or absolute paths in your projects?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem (Linux, Mac OS X, Windows):

1. if you place all the layer files in the same folder as the QGIS project file, no problem.
2. otherwise, look at the .qgs file. It is an XML file with a tag named `<datasource>` containing the paths of the layers (one per layer).

[image]

Open this file,  and replace all the `/Users/me/` with your paths.

I automated the process with a Python script using ElementTree